# rviz problem with ubuntu 10.04

Tags: rviz, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,guys
i despair over an error message .
i can not start rviz, and dont know why.i use ubuntu 10.04
rviz starts with ubuntu higher versions,but i don't like that.Want to use 10.04
so my graphic card is not guilty.
where is the problem?any body here who can help me ?
thanks,regards
adrian

here the terminal output :

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [16798]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 1e62e032-4512-11e1-9e45-90004e158d56
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [16812]
started core service [/rosout]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [16824]
process[rviz-3]: started with pid [16827]
The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
(Details: serial 22 error_code 9 request_code 136 minor_code 3)
(Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
[rviz-3] process has died [pid 16827, exit code 1].
log files: /home/adrian/.ros/log/1e62e032-4512-11e1-9e45-90004e158d56/rviz-3*.log
^C[robot_state_publisher-2] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12711/rviz-problem-with-ubuntu-10.04/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-01-22**:
What kind of graphics card do you have? Which driver are you using for it (if there are restricted drivers available)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds similar to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/2775/rviz-crashing-at-startup-with-baddrawable). Try the troubleshooting steps linked there.

Generally, this "BadDrawable" error is related to either your GPU being too old to run rviz or a problem with the driver. Since you say it starts okay on newer versions of Ubuntu, my guess would be that the driver for your GPU included in the kernel used in 10.04 has a bug that was fixed in newer versions of Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2012-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3